# Reading/Writing SQLite3 database to OneDrive with WinRT 8.1

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I am having a problem getting an SQLite3 database to work with OneDrive.  I have no problems running the database from `ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder`, but when I try to add a `FolderPicker` to allow the user to specify a folder to store the database, I keep getting a `CannotOpen` error from SQLite.

I am adding a token for the folder to the `FutureAccessList` like so:

```
// give us a consent to use the folder
var folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
_currentFolder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

// after that, we can store the folder for future reuse
var pickedFolderToken = StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(_currentFolder);
ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.Add("FolderTokenSettingsKey", pickedFolderToken);
```

As I said, the application runs fine when using `RoamingFolder`, but I am trying to get the database to be stored on remote storage so I can keep it synchronized between multiple devices.

I initially thought that `RoamingFolder` would be synchronized across multiple devices (as long as it is the same Microsoft account logged in), but that does not appear to be the case, so I am trying to get it to work with SkyDrive, or some other remote storage service.

The SQLite3 database is configured to create the database if it does not exist, and I have tried both scenarios with the same result - `CannotOpen` in either case.  Anyone know if this is allowed in WinRT 8.1 applications?  My other option is to copy the database from  to the `RoamingFolder` and access that copy from the application, and then copy back to  when writing to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite works with native Windows filesystem APIs (Win32), but the pickers (like `FolderPicker`) and the `FutureAccessList` work only with brokered filesystem APIs (`Windows.Storage`). There is no way to mix the two at the same time.

But items in your roaming folder **should** get copied to other devices with the same Microsoft Account, although it isn't instantaneous. How long have you waited to see if it turns up? How big is the file? Did you read [this topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465094.aspx) and related items on MSDN?

Otherwise, yes your work-around of copying the file from the brokered location into your app's storage, then modifying it, then copying it back again after it has been closed would work.

Comment: Right now the database is only about 600 kilobytes.  I have implemented the copy/modify/copy method for now, but I am hoping to come up with a better solution in the long run.  The thing about the roaming folder, is at least as far as I can tell, it is still storing everything under `AppData\Local\....\<app folder>\RoamingData\database.sqlite`, and not in the actual `AppData\Roaming` folder tree.

Comment: What do you see as the value for your [roaming quota](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingstoragequota.aspx)? If it is less than 600k, nothing will sync.

Comment: Ah, good to know.  I think I will go with the local storage in that case.  What I am hoping to achieve though, is have the user be able to select their own folder for where they want the file to be located.  In some (probably most) cases, my application will used by a single user on a single device, but in some cases they may wish to use it on multiple devices and share data/settings.  In my testing, I am trying to get it to sync with OneDrive, which (mostly) works via copying the file to local, then copying the file back to OneDrive after any edits.